Ignition Gazebo Transform Control does not display Arrows
I am currently running ignition Fortress with ros iron on Ubuntu 22.04.
The Problem i am facing is related to the GUI. I'm able to spawn in a box, but the transform control plugin does not allow me to move it around, also the GUI is not loading properly.
I tried a fresh install and i am still facing the same problem.
I'm starting gazebo with:
ign gazebo
which gives me the error message:
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
My Gui.log is added below.
I'm at a total loss here since nothing seems to work for me, so any help would really be appreciated.
(2024-08-21T16:19:50.71623413) (2024-08-21T16:19:50.71646847) [Dbg] [Application.cc:92] Initializing application.
(2024-08-21T16:19:50.72888027) (2024-08-21T16:19:50.72893116) [GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:555] Create main window
(2024-08-21T16:19:50.218433920) (2024-08-21T16:19:50.218441214) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:112:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo() { ... }
(2024-08-21T16:19:50.218472231) (2024-08-21T16:19:50.218475868) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:105:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo() { ... }
(2024-08-21T16:19:50.218489173) (2024-08-21T16:19:50.218492629) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:98:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo() { ... }
(2024-08-21T16:19:50.221967106) (2024-08-21T16:19:50.221973007) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:102:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo() { ... }
(2024-08-21T16:19:50.223124079) (2024-08-21T16:19:50.223129669) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:27:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo() { ... }
(2024-08-21T16:19:58.209523082) Add [CameraTracking] via menu
(2024-08-21T16:19:58.209548670) (2024-08-21T16:19:58.209557175) [GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:426] Loading plugin [CameraTracking]
(2024-08-21T16:19:58.261932443) (2024-08-21T16:19:58.261943674) [GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [Camera tracking] to main window
(2024-08-21T16:19:58.262179623) (2024-08-21T16:19:58.262187638) [GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [CameraTracking] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gui-6/plugins/libCameraTracking.so]
(2024-08-21T16:20:02.684197800) (2024-08-21T16:20:02.684212047) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:02.734450116) (2024-08-21T16:20:02.734463311) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:02.767531434) (2024-08-21T16:20:02.767544408) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:02.817717667) (2024-08-21T16:20:02.817734559) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:02.867662250) (2024-08-21T16:20:02.867680254) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:02.934416799) (2024-08-21T16:20:02.934439721) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:03.1404591) (2024-08-21T16:20:03.1428235) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:03.84503903) (2024-08-21T16:20:03.84523670) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:08.801163871) (2024-08-21T16:20:08.801180693) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:09.101767862) (2024-08-21T16:20:09.101788010) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:09.200501393) (2024-08-21T16:20:09.200538171) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:09.366984860) (2024-08-21T16:20:09.367022830) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:10.10393814) (2024-08-21T16:20:10.10406237) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:10.100246503) (2024-08-21T16:20:10.100260799) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:12.242632944) (2024-08-21T16:20:12.242647862) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:12.279426553) (2024-08-21T16:20:12.279438505) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:12.416768887) (2024-08-21T16:20:12.416777463) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:13.666725215) (2024-08-21T16:20:13.666741606) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:13.700216776) (2024-08-21T16:20:13.700226194) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:13.750157761) (2024-08-21T16:20:13.750187216) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:13.800267881) (2024-08-21T16:20:13.800280014) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:13.850269789) (2024-08-21T16:20:13.850283735) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:13.916906928) (2024-08-21T16:20:13.916921815) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:13.983736764) (2024-08-21T16:20:13.983745410) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:14.67268258) (2024-08-21T16:20:14.67279679) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.89957145) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.89981250) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.156674479) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.156694487) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.223287890) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.223304401) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:130: TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.913067304) Add [WorldControl] via menu
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.913104634) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.913116797) [GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:426] Loading plugin [WorldControl]
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.921313642) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.921323861) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] file::/WorldControl/WorldControl.qml:30:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo() { ... }
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.921502314) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.921510169) [GUI] [Err] [WorldControl.cc:145] Must specify a  for world control requests, or set the MainWindow's [worldNames] property.
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.939844657) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.939855457) [GUI] [Msg] Added plugin [World control] to main window
(2024-08-21T16:20:39.939887577) (2024-08-21T16:20:39.939894069) [GUI] [Msg] Loaded plugin [WorldControl] from path [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ign-gui-6/plugins/libWorldControl.so]
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.938351424) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.938364097) [GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:140] Terminating application.
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941617190) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941624614) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:52: TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialogOnExitText' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941650172) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941653969) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:54: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exitDialogShowCloseGui' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941668376) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941672173) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:53: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exitDialogShowShutdown' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941700375) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941703952) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:251: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDrawer' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941721575) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941725182) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/SideDrawer.qml:93: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDefaultDrawerOpts' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941741111) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941745029) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/IgnSplit.qml:56: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginCount' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941762271) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941765867) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:41: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toolBarColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941778872) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941782398) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:42: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toolBarTextColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941803838) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941807605) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:43: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toolBarColorDark' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941821321) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941825008) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:44: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toolBarTextColorDark' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941838122) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941841659) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:45: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941855004) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941858731) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:46: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarTextColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941872005) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941875542) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:47: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarColorDark' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941888676) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941892193) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:48: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarTextColorDark' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941905177) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941908874) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:50: TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultExitAction' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941921207) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941924713) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:51: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDialogOnExit' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941938499) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941942016) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:55: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exitDialogShutdownText' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941955581) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941959338) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:56: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exitDialogCloseGuiText' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941971821) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941975358) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:66: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toolBarColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.941989184) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.941994574) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:76: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toolBarTextColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942025050) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942031643) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:/qml/PluginMenu.qml:126: TypeError: Cannot call method 'PluginListModel' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942065887) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942069904) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:219: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPluginMenu' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942092847) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942096403) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:202: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDrawer' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942111061) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942114738) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] qrc:qml/Main.qml:188: TypeError: Cannot read property 'showDrawer' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942138853) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942142489) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] file::qml/IgnCard.qml:128: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942168949) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942172736) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] file::qml/IgnCard.qml:139: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarTextColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942188124) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942191851) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] file::qml/IgnCard.qml:128: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarColorLight' of null
(2024-08-21T16:20:42.942321202) (2024-08-21T16:20:42.942325771) [GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:797] [QT] file::qml/IgnCard.qml:139: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluginToolBarTextColorLight' of null
